# Simple page host on github.io returns 404

Tags: github

My GitHub URL is `https://github.com/qiaoba` and `https://github.com/qiaoba/qiaoba.github.io` is the repository on my master branch.

But I get a 404 page returned when I'm trying to visit `qiaoba.github.io`.

Why?

Comment: What do you get when visiting url qiaoba.github.io ? @w3d

Comment: Sorry, misread,  yes `http://qiaoba.github.io` returns a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **CNAME** file with content: 
`qiaoba.github.io`

May be it will work.

Comment: I've setted it according to the document _https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working_ . But it doesn't work. And I don't think there is any relation between CNAME configuration and the return of 404 when visition url _qiaoba.github.io_.

Comment: I've forked your repository, and it works fine for me, I think you should delete that repository and recreate a new one. You can check this answer, may be it can be helpful.
[how-to-fix-page-404-on-github-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-page-404-on-github-page)
Hope you can fix this.

Comment: It's not the reason. I got a mail from github which told me that I need a verified email address in my GitHub account to publish Pages. I didn't open my email before. After adding another email address to verify, it works!  Thank you.